# Unity DI misbehaving on async operations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous, dependency-injection, unity-container

We have a legacy multi-tenant (where each tenant has it's own database, but they all share the same code and VMs) system built on asp.net MVC 4. Due to some performance problems we started to change it a little, piece by piece.

One thing we did is to work with DI/IoC using unity. So far the only thing registered on the container is the EF DbContext using `PerRequestLifetimeManager`. So far no other items are registered. Whenever a Service or Controller gets instatiated,

Another thing we did is to make some operations async... we plan to make them all async but we're going one by one.

Our in-house tests were successful and we deployed to production.

After a few hours of real traffic, we started to notice some problems... inexplicable erros where the system reported a bunch of things, for which, root cause was: "Id does not exists". These were very far apart for a specific tenant (happening less than 10 times a day per tenant - avg usage of 3k operations per day per tenant) but at a grand total, this became very concerning. Capturing and executing manually always returned the expected result.

By mistake, one dev at a certain point had logged the full connection string EF was using, and for our surprise, the wrong database was being hit! client A was indeed trying to read something from client B database!

Looking all over the place, we went through `TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled` and `<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />` but the errors are still happening...

We figured that there are 2 possible locations for the root cause here: Either we're screwing up when creating the DbContext or unity is giving up the wrong instance when we call for `Resolve`.
Because the creation logic did not change at all and this was not happening before, we believe that Unity is at fault here.

It's important to notice that, as far as we know, no sync operations that use DI (about 95% of the system now, 5% are async ops) ever had such problems.

Anyone has any idea of what might be going on?

Details:
-Hosted on Azure App Services, framework version 4.6
-Horizontal scale. But this happens even when only 1 instance can handle the load

Comment: This question is way too broad. You will have to come up with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without such example, there is nothing much we can do here.

Comment: Unity is no longer being maintained (for several years now) and has fallen behind in features from other DI containers. So why is it that people still expect support for it? Frankly, I am tired of seeing questions for this defunct container on StackOverflow asking for answers to problems that could be avoided by switching to a modern one.

Comment: @NightOwl888 i didn't know that! thats a really helpful information! tks a lot for sharing! I kinda suspected that but could not find an direct post or something like that... where did you read that?

Comment: Here is a post [The Future of Unity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/08/21/the-future-of-unity/) from 2015. Of course, that is only when they handed the project off to new owners. It also talks about the failed attempt to upgrade Unity to version 4.

Comment: @NightOwl888 given the scenario above, any suggestions for replacement? Ninject perhaps?

Comment: Personally, I like StructureMap. But Autofac, Windsor, and SimpleInjector are also solid containers. Ninject is okay, but sometimes hard to configure and [among the slowest](https://github.com/danielpalme/IocPerformance).

Comment: @NightOwl888, Stackoverflow is a community-driven site, so it is perfectly fine to ask questions about outdated technologies. Unity sure isn't maintained anymore, and you sure shouldn't use it when starting a new project, but that by itself doesn't invalidate the question. That said, the OP seems to just started using Unity, so in this sense I absolutely agree with you: Unity is most likely a bad choice for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve everything up-front (on the constructor for example) and it will all be fine...